# How to rename a node module on npmjs.org?

Tags: node.js, npm

I have published a node module on npmjs.org, but I have realized that its name might be quite confusing and not a very good description of what it does. So, is there some way to rename the module, or do I just have to live with the name I gave it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `npm unpublish` it and the `npm publish` the new name.